# How to retrieve the rendered html for a control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

How do I retrieve the html rendered for a web control in ASP .NET programmatically?

For instance something like:

```
dim controlHTML as string = myControl.GetHTML()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
using (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
    mycontrol.RenderControl(hw);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to actually call it's .RenderMethod, and pass in a HtmlTextWriter, and get the contents from that.